# How do I get the Mammoth Tusk Powder?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the Unmelting Snow and the Brair Heart, but I can't get the Mammoth Tusk Powder. It does not show up anywhere. Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this? I'm playing on PS3. I can't find anything that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The Mammoth Tusk Powder for the [Repairing the Phial quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Repairing_the_Phial) is found in the Stonehill Bluff giant camp between Dawnstar and Whiterun, inside a large stone bowl near the bonfire.

Also keep in mind Powdered Mammoth Tusk != Mammoth Tusk Powder. The first is an alchemy ingredient and won't work for the quest, the second is the unique quest item you need.

Comment: not at stonehill bluff and the powdered mammoth tusk isn't counting

Comment: You get Powdered Mammoth Tusk in your Alchemy Tower, not Mammoth Tusk Powder.